# Turn regular array into assoc array in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to turn a regular array to an assoc array, prefereably **without** a loop/for/foreach/etc.

Is there a native PHP method for that?

```
$arr = ['bambi','fortress','lineage','treehouse'];
```

Would turn into:

```
$arr = [1 => 'bambi', 2 => 'fortress', 3 => 'lineage', 4 => 'treehouse'];
```

Thanks.

Comment: _Would turn into:..._ Your array **is** already in that format

Comment: @B001ᛦ is right. Just point out that it starts at 0 position

Comment: learn from here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp

Comment: @STACKOVERFLOW - LET ME DELETE THIS QUESTION.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `range` for the keys, and combine them with the values:

```
$arr = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), $arr);
```

This creates an array starting at index 1.

FYI, you already have an equivalent array, but simply one that starts at *0*.

Comment: excellent, looks good, need to test on something, will revert back here to let u know.